# app size increases from 3.5 MB to 3.2 GB

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory, memory-management

I have an application which was created using iOS 7 and updated using iOS 8.2.

iPad also have iOS 8.3

When I install the application, it was 3.5 MB.

***After using the application for few weeks, clients starts complaining that automatically restart after some interval of time.***

*In app, every 2 seconds I have a webservice call (after completion of webservice) to check if new data is present. That's it...*

After further investigation what I noticed that app size is showing to 3.2 GB. (I go to Usage to check whether iPad have remaining memory or not and there I found my app was using 3.2 GB which shocked me)

***Any idea what causes to increase  the app size?***

---

### Edit 1

I was hotel application where list of orders were displaying. I was checking for new orders and incase if it is there, I was adding in array and reloading tableview. That's it.

I was not saving anything on the iPad.

The only heavy thing was, I was calling webservice every 2 seconds after webservice call is finished.

***This app was connected to local server so there was no point of wait time for the webservice call. The webservice call was within half second.***

Comment: If it's the app size on device, then: Are you saving any data to your documents dictionary? Are you creating temporary files that don't get deleted? If it's the size in memory: have you tried to find leaks using Instruments?

Comment: @Sulthan : No, I am not saving anything... its just a list of orders... if new order comes, i was adding in the array... that's it...

Comment: There is probably a memory leak. Use Instruments (Profiling -> Leaks) to find it

Comment: Just Clear all details of objects and dictionary, array before calling webservice

Comment: @AabasahebDeshpande : No, that's not an issue...

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode and go to the Window -> Devices menu. Plug in your iPhone and select it on the left column.

On the right, select you app in the list of installed apps, and at the bottom click the wheel and choose "download container".

The container of your app will be downloaded on your Desktop (if its' 3G big, it will take some time...). You can then right-click on it and choose "Show package content".

You can then edit your question and tell us what is taking so much space.

Comment: I will do what you are saying when I have the iPad tomorrow... For today, I delete and re-install the app to check what size of app will become tomorrow...